# How does statsmodels calculate t-statistics and p-values?

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, least-squares

I've spent the last two hours running through statsmodels source code trying to understand the calculation done in a t-test for a simple OLS. Specifically, I'm interested in the calculation in the case that we are testing the significance of the constant and the coefficient, for example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
...
model = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(x))
results = model.fit(use_t = True)
hypothesis_params = pd.Series({'beta': 1, 'const': 1})
results.t_test(hypothesis_params).pvalue
```

I've deduced that statsmodels uses scipy.stats.t.sf for the p-value, but I'm really struggling to follow the complete logic mathematically. If anyone could explain the calculations to me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The Stats SE thread [Understanding t-test for linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344006/understanding-t-test-for-linear-regression) might be useful.